# Sigma or Summation function in Excel

Tags: excel

Given a value (in a cell), calculate a formula like this:

Ʃ(3i+1) for i from 0 to the value specified in the cell.

SUM(), SERIESSUM() are not suitable in this case. How can I do this in Excel? Much thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yea, I tried sum(), seriessum() and many

Comment: this would be (with your value in A1), `=SUMPRODUCT(3*(ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,A1+1))-1)+1)`

Comment: what is `3i` mean? if i = 0, `3i` = 30 or 31?

Comment: @pcw please check [THIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation)

Comment: `S=(n+1)(3n+2)/2`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Demo as below graph:

Write in B2 Cell with `=SUM(3*(ROW(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("1:",A2+1)))-1)+1)` then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: @DirkReichel, I am sorry.  What does the volatile mean?

Comment: the formula will calculate every time excel calculates, even nothing has changed

Comment: @DirkReichel, I do not know that.  Does it matter?

Comment: not directly for this case... just keep in mind: "if possible, avoid volatile functions"... they may add up if used often (specifically when used with array formulas), then every action will trigger a new calculation which may end with excel freeze...

Answer (score 13):

To leave you all options, just use this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(3*(ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,B1-A1+1))-(1-A1))+1)
```

A1 is the lower limit and B1 is the upper limit... will also work for ranges like `i = -5 to -3` ;)

Comment: and avoids array formula.

Answer (score 3):

Use the **array formula**:

```
=SUM(3*ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & A1))+1)+1
```

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Comment: This answer will return `#REF!`, if i = 0.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need complexe functions, Just calculate (max-min+1)*((formula min)+(formula max))/2

In other words range times the average of formula min/max

Here is an example using Mac numbers for a range min=1/max=5

[image]

For the average you can use the function AVG but this is the no functions solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is Generic Way:
Ʃ(3*i+1) for i from 0 to 10 = `SUMPRODUCT(3*SEQUENCE((A1+1),1,0,1)+1)`
Where i is in cell=A1

Answer (score -1):

[To complement Dirk Reichel's answer (I added a **$** at "ROW(A$1)":

`=SUMPRODUCT(3*(ROW(A$1:INDEX(A:A,B1-A1+1))-(1-A1))+1)`

Here is what it looks like. (see the image)

No indirect, no array, and can be cut past anywhere. (Needed the $ sign to be cut and past anywhere)]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

What about

```
=(3/2*n+1)*(n+1)
```

for `0` as lower bound and `n` is your upper bound