# Excel Sigma Summation - Quadratic Expression

Tags: excel

I am trying to make a Variance summation in Excel. I know there is a function for it, but I want to use the Sigma summation:

[image]

I found some threads, but all of them assume a non-quadratic expression. This one for example: [Sigma or Summation function in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38044955/sigma-or-summation-function-in-excel/38045096)

I have the given data in Excel, and just need to put it together in this Sigma Summation. How would I write the function to make it work?

Comment: Excel has a built-in function `VAR.S` for calculating the sample variance (divisor = n-1). There's also `VAR.P` for calculating the population variance (divisor = n).

Comment: @xidgel I know. Read the question please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer myself after playing with the expression I got from the other thread that I mentioned. The problem was that I did not know how to make it squared, because I did not see where the variable was exactly.

In the end, this function did it for me. The X variable was entered as data starting from E31:E35 (which was a small example to be able to control the answer). The variance was then calculated.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMSQ(E31:E35-D37))/(C34-1)
```

The key to this was to understand that the SUMPRODUCT function returns the sum of the range.

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all you could use the alternate variance formula

[image]

which is simpler to calculate (replace n by n-1 for a sample).

But if the question is to implement the formula in the question in Excel, the literal answer would be to replace each element of the formula with an Excel function giving you

```
=SUMSQ(A1:A10-AVERAGE(A1:A10))/(COUNT(A1:A10)-1)
```

This does work, providing (a) there are no blank cells in the data and (b) you enter it as an array formula.

To ignore blanks, use either

```
=SUMSQ(IF(A1:A10<>"",A1:A10-AVERAGE(A1:A10)))/(COUNT(A1:A10)-1)
```

entered as an array formula

or

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A10<>"")*(A1:A10-AVERAGE(A1:A10))^2)/(COUNT(A1:A10)-1)
```

which doesn't have to be entered as an array formula.

Of course you have the choice of using a helper column to hold the intermediate values as well.

[image]