# Product and Summation with Indexed Variable in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can products and summations with indexed variables be done in Excel?

For example below, using the indexed values in A1:A5

```
   A  B  C
1  1
2  3
3  6
4  8
5  9
```

[image: index]

[image: product]

[image: summation]

I have been looking at the answers here, but they don't cover the indexed variable

[Sigma or Summation function in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38044955/879601)

Answers eschewing array formulas would be preferable.  All welcome though.

***Edit***

Trying chris neilsen's [adapted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64093117/879601) on Excel for Mac 2011, Windows Office 2010 and Mac Office 2019.  All produce '4'.

[image]

but it does work on Office 365.

[image]

Comment: why no array formulas?

Comment: @teylyn I'd like to keep the solution as basic as possible, but if an array formula is the way, no problem.

Comment: @teylyn Dirk Reichel's one line formula [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38045255/879601) appealed, but I could not modify it to a product nor add an indexed variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Excel 365, the Dynamic Array functions can help here (this assumes that column A has *only* the data you want to process.  However, the data doesn't have to start in row 1, and doesn't have to be contiguous)

Product

```
=LET(Data,FILTER(A:A,A:A<>""),PRODUCT(SEQUENCE(ROWS(Data))*3+Data))
```

Sum

```
=LET(Data,FILTER(A:A,A:A<>""),SUM(SEQUENCE(ROWS(Data))*3+Data))
```

[image]

---

If you *don't* have Excel 365, then the [answer by Dick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38045255) can be adapted.  This *does* assume the data starts in row 1, and that the data is contiguous.  It requires that cell B1 contains the count of values (which could be a formula)

<sub>Note: I don't have a non-365 version to test on, so can't be entirely sure these will work.  You *might* have to enter them as an array formula (or use `SUMPRODUCT` for the sum version, can't offer an alternative for the `PRODUCT` version</sub>

```
=PRODUCT(3*(ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,B1)))+A1:INDEX(A:A,B1))
=SUM(3*(ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,B1)))+A1:INDEX(A:A,B1))
```

[image]
<sub>Note: there is an error in that answer, corrected here</sub>

Comment: Hi, sorry I'm just getting an error with the adapted answer.  Btw, is there a variable in there that looks up the value from, say A3, for `x3 = 6`?

Comment: "getting an error" doesn't really tell me much.  And I don't understand what you mean by "is there a variable in there that looks up the value from, say A3, for x3 = 6".  Please edit your question to explain

Comment: Hi. Thanks for adding screenshots. I had interpreted your answer correctly.  Maybe it only works in 365.  I added screenshots to my post.

Comment: Does it work as an array formula (completed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter)

Comment: I just tried the adapted answer on 365 and it worked.  Nice.  No Ctrl-Shift-Enter required.  I tried Ctrl-Shift-Enter on the other version but nothing happened.  Maybe a Mac keyboard thing.  Great to have a working solution.  Would be nice to figure it out for the old versions.  Thanks for your answer.